# Gatsby: Get all images with GraphQL query from a path stored in a json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

### Context

I am trying to make a Gallery. It should display images from different occasions like a blog.

For this I have a JSON file in which all posts (title, slug, date and images-folder-path) are stored. To display them I'm using GraphQL.

### Problem

My problem now is to display all images for the respective post. In the JSON file only the path to the images is stored.

*JSON structure:*

```
[
 {
  "title": "Gallery 1",
  "slug": "gallery-1",
  "date": "02.01.2022",
  "images": "./gallery-1/"
 },
 {
  "title": "Gallery 2",
  "slug": "gallery-2",
  "date": "15.01.2022",
  "images": "./gallery-2/"
 }
]
```

Now for **Gallery 1** I would like to get all the images stored in the *./gallery-1/* folder and so on.

```
query MyQuery {
  allGalleriesJson {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        slug
        date
        images
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this GraphQL command, I get the string of the path. But now I would like to get all images in the folder with this string. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's your project structure? I mean, where do you place the `allGalleriesJson` query?

Comment: I store it in the _gatsby-node.js_ file which is stored on the top level of the project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `filter` filter (quite redundant) to get all the images in the `/gallery-1/` (or each gallery) folder.

To do that, you just need to provide a context variable to your template, using the `context` available in your `createPage` function.

```
createPage({
  path: node.slug,
  component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/your-template-file.js`),
  context: {
    slug: node.slug,
  },
})
```

*Note: this is an abstraction since no boilerplate has been provided. Tweak it as you wish but get the idea of passing a `slug` for each gallery object.*

After that, in your template (`your-template-file.js`) you'll need to filter the query using the `slug` provided (different for each page)

```
export const query = graphql`
  query TemplateQuery($slug: String!) {
    allGalleriesJson(filter: {fileAbsolutePath: {eq: $slug  }}) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          date
          images
        }
      }
    }
```

*Note: the `allGalleriesJson` may be different or you may have `galleriesJson` available. If so, use it, it's more performant to point a specific node than all of them*

Here I'm using the `eq` (equals) filter but you have a bunch available: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/

In the same way, you can use absolute paths (`fileAbsolutePath`) or relative. Test your queries in the GraphiQL playground (`localhost:8000/___graphql`).

Despite the query or the snippets may differ from this example, get the idea:

- Create pages for each JSON object position (`gatsby-node.js` + `createPage`)
- Pass the `slug` variable into the template through the context
- Use the context to filter the `allGalleriesJson` to get your folder images